# What's the correct term or phrase for "Breaking a complex problem down into its fundamental tenets"?

Tags: terminology

Any problem I encounter, I distill down into fundamental tenets to create a model where the relationships between the distinct components of the problem are clear and more easily defined / discussed.

I call this "modeling the problem," but it occurs to me there might be a more formal term for it, since I just intuitively used that one without any formal education in the matter. Does Philosophy have any specific terms for this process?

Comment: Interesting question.

Comment: Analysis.........